# Can't git clone by adding ssh-key in Node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, ssh-keys

```
  # Write the SSH-KEY to the disk
  fs.writeFile "/cgrepos/.ssh/#{repo.id}.pub", repo.public_key, (err) ->
    throw err if err

    fs.writeFile "/cgrepos/.ssh/#{repo.id}", repo.private_key, (err) ->
      throw err if err

      exec "chmod 400 /cgrepos/.ssh/#{repo.id} && eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add /cgrepos/.ssh/#{repo.id}", (error) ->
        throw error if error
        # First, delete the git repo on the hard drive, if it exists
        exec "rm -rf #{git_location}", options, (error) ->
          throw error if error
          # Second, clone the repo into the location
          console.log "Cloning repo #{repo.id}: #{repo.repo_name} into #{git_location}. This could take a minute"
          exec "git clone #{repo.url} #{git_location}", options, (error) ->
            throw error if error
```

I'm trying that in node (using `coffee` for those that are awesome). But for some reason, when it runs, it gives me an error: `Error: Command failed: conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I run those commands from command line directly, everything seems to work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this directly with `ssh`, taking git out of the equation? Although you're unlikely to get anything useful out of Bitbucket's server (from the error message I assume that's what you're using) you should see "You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled." if it works; you can try `ssh -v` to debug if that doesn't work.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to make a wrapper shell script that runs `exec ssh -v "$@"` and set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable so that git will run SSH in verbose mode. Then you can see how `git` is running SSH and that might give you some clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to execute `git clone` process from node.js, it runs in different environment.

When you use `git clone` on protected (on ssh protocol) repository, `ssh-agent` first tries to authenticate you with provided public key. Since `exec` use different runtime environment for each call, even if you're adding your private key explicitly, it won't work because of different runtime environment.

When authenticating in ssh, git clone looks for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Generally this env variable has the path of your password keyring service like (gnome-keyring or kde-wallet).

Try this to check it first.

```
env | grep -i ssh
```

It should list SSH_AGENT_PID and SSH_AUTH_SOCK. The problem is when running `git clone` these environ variables aren't set. So you can set them (just SSH_AUTH_SOCK is enough) as options in exec function call. Look [here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) on how to pass env key-pairs to exec.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('git clone cloneurl', {
  cwd: cwdhere,      // working dir path for git clone
  env: {
           envVar1: envVarValue1,
           SSH_AUTH_SOCK: socketPathHere
       } 
}, callback);
```

If this doesn't work, try to execute `ssh -vvv user@git-repo-host` in exec function. See output of this process, you'll find error.

If the error says `debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey).`, then add a host alias to $HOME/.ssh/config file like this.

```
Host hostalias
 Hostname git-repo-host
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_private_key_path
```

This will use provided private key to all authntication requests to specified host. In this option, you can also change your `origin's` url to use hostalias configured in file above.
`reporoot/.git/config` file will look like this.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = user@hostalias:repo.git
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this programatically for potentially thousands of repos that I don't own or control. I generate the `ssh` key and our users will add them to their deployment key. So I'm not sure if this will work

Comment: In that case hostalias way is not applicable. But you should try to set proper environment for that process.